# wicket table with heading spanning multiple columns

Tags: wicket

How do I create a table with multiple columns having same heading.

e.g: a table with 5 columns c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 where c1,c2 and c3 have same heading; c4 and c5 have same heading.
And all the columns are sortable.

I am not sure but headerstoolbar could be one way to do it. I searched, but couldn't find a good example for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to roll your own HeadersToolbar variant that does this. There are multiple ways to achieve this, the easiest may be:

1. Copy code from HeadersToolbar into a new class
2. Modify the RefreshingView's getItemModels method so it only returns the list populated with the columns you want (you can do this via an extra marker interface on your column objects or by adding the configuration externally to this new toolbar class)
3. In populateItem make sure you use an AttributeModifier to add appropriate colspan attributes to the columns you need to span multiple columns.